# Choosing k out of n waiters to satisfy all customers

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, graph-theory, matching

Suppose there are n waiters and m customers. Each waiter can serve a known subset of these customers such that each customer can be served by at least one waiter(there may be overlaps).

Given k(k < n),how is it possible to determine whether k waiters can be selected such that all the customers are satisfied?

If it is possible to make such a selection, how to find those k waiters?

My first approach would be to order the waiters by the number of customers they can serve, greatest first, and see whether the first k waiters can satisfy all the customers. But this seems non-optimal.

Comment: Your post is not a question and Stack Overflow is designed to answer questions related to software engineering rather than general algorithmic problems and their applications.

Comment: @MartinMacak: The post *is* a question, and if algorithms are off-topic at SO, the existence of the `algorithm` tag is certainly puzzling.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: This is the Set Cover problem.  Unfortunately, it's NP-hard, so no efficient (polynomial-time) algorithms are known that solve it.  I suggest googling that term to learn more.

Comment: Thanks @j_random_hacker ! That helped. Just needed to know the name of the general problem related to this.